# RewriteRule for 404 does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/.+ /admin/admin_panel.php [R=404,L,NC]
```

The first part should rewrite requests in form of `http://example.com/url` to `http://example.com/url.php` and it works correctly. The second part should redirect requests to non-existent files in `/admin/` to `/admin/admin_panel.php`, but this time it does not work. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the second part by the following code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/admin_panel\.php
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/admin_panel.php [L,NC]
```

This flag `[R=404,L,NC]` will make `404` status and do not redirect to `admin_panel.php` .

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r):

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

using `[R=404]` drops the redirection string and the rule does not work in the way one would like it to work. The solution is either to use `[R=3xx]` to make the redirection work, or use `[R=404]` without redirectiong. Another way is to use the `ErrorDocument 404 somefile.php` syntax. In this example the solution would be to create two different files:

*/.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

And */admin/.htaccess*:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /admin/admin_panel.php
```

Also, in this solution the rule from root directory `.htaccess` file works as intended.

EDIT:

Please be aware, that [Mohammed Elhag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363271/1223773) below could also work here